# Why do i get bad access

Tags: c, ansi-c

I  have a struct as follows

```
struct cmd{

  char **tokenized_cmd;
  int num_params;
}
```

in some function with the signature 
i have the following

```
void parse_cmd(cmd, char *line){

    char *token;
    char *saveptr;
    char *delim_space;
    char *delim_comma;
    char *delim_new_line;
    char **result;
    int i;
    int j=0;
    command.num_params = 0;
    delim_space = " ";
    delim_comma = ",";
    delim_new_line = "\n";
    if(line!=NULL){
        line = strtok(line,delim_new_line);
        token = strtok_r(line,delim_space,&saveptr);
    }
    result[j]=token;
    j++;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++){
        token = strtok_r(NULL, delim_comma, &saveptr);
        if(token!=NULL){
            result[j] = token;
            j++;
        }else{
            result[j]='\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    command.tokenized_cmd = result;
    command.num_params = j;

    if(command.tokenized_cmd[0] == '\0'){
     printf("empty");
    }

}
```

why does this piece of code :

```
if(command.tokenized_cmd[0] == '\0'){
     printf("empty");
    }
```

cause bad access error ?

this doesnt seem to fix the problem:

```
 command.tokenized_cmd = malloc(sizeof(result));
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        command.tokenized_cmd[i]= malloc(sizeof(result[i]));
        command.tokenized_cmd[i] = result[i];
    }
    command.num_params = j;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not appear to allocate space for `result`, and so this step should fail to provide anything accessible:

```
command.tokenized_cmd = result;
```

If `result` is storing multiple strings, then you need to allocate space for storing however many `char *` (strings) with `malloc()`.

In addition, for each individual string or `char *`, you need to allocate space for *that* with `malloc()`.

When you're done with `result` or `tokenized_cmd` and no longer need it, you may need to use `free()` to recover the memory you've allocated, to prevent a memory leak. For a double pointer (`char **`) that you are done with, you must free both the strings and the pointers to those strings.

Comment: how do i know how much space to allocate for it ?

Comment: You might figure out how many strings you are storing in `result`, allocating space with `malloc()` (for example) for storing pointers for those strings. For each string, you would also need to allocate space for that string, perhaps using common string length functions and `malloc()`.

When you're done with `result`, be sure to run `free()` on each string pointer and each pointer to a string pointer, or you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: so what do i actually need to do ?

Comment: You need to start by learning basic memory allocation and pointer management techniques in C. This is core stuff. Start with a small test program that just works with a `char *` to store a string, then work into your program a `char **` that stores pointers to a set of strings, along with `malloc()` calls for each pointer.